# paypal sandbox error

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I have setup paypal sandbox which i have used before with no problems but now its causing me lots of issues and im not sure how to narrow down the problem.

I have setup a business through paypal sandbox and i have setup a personal account i have coded my ipn for it to run on purchase which i can use paypals built in IPN test tools to run a test and this come back successful no issues.

The problem i am getting i have created a button with my business account and email and my custom values but every time i run the code to make a payment i get the following error.

> An error occurred while processing your request. Before submitting
>   this again, log in and check your Account History to ensure that the
>   transaction didn't complete.

Can anyone suggest ways in which to narrow down the issue im scratching my head....

Thanks

Comment: "Before submitting this again, log in and check your Account History to ensure that the transaction didn't complete." Have you had a look?

Comment: Hi Adrian yes i have checked my account history and its all blank no activity and also nothing for IPN history really weird. Going to try and setup a new business account.

Comment: Nope tried with complete new setup and different browsers etc...

Comment: Ok Weird but narrowing it down it works if i manually enter the test account info rather than login with paypal account...

Comment: to answer that , what browser do you use ?